# How does the Loss of a Neural Network effect training

Tags: neural-networks, training-error

Suppose I have a neural network, say an input layer taking in vectors $i \in \mathbb{R}^d$, a hidden relu layer, and then a softmax output layer with a cross entropy loss (with no biases added for simplicity). My question, which starts out abstract but I hope to make more clear, is how does the loss effect training?

Suppose also that we are training with Stochastic Gradient Descent, i.e. a weight update of the form

$w_{i+1} = w_i - \nabla L (w_i)$ for our cross entropy loss $L$. At each mini batch of $n$ labelled training examples, we  compute $\nabla L (w_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \nabla L_{w_i}(x_i)$, and then decrement the weights by this value (assuming for simplicity no regularizations/weight decay etc.)

What will be the difference in the update $-\nabla L(w_i)$ if the loss is very large, or very small?

Further if at a given step the loss is $0$, or very close to $0$, then it seems the update value should be very small, but is this always the case?

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Writing out the gradient of softmax and inspecting the values the gradient takes when the loss is zero should immediately answer your question.